# Hash with keys as array - How to turn into a normal hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, multiple-columns

I've been using arel/rails and have figured out how to get my group by statement working correctly. Using multiple columns it gives an output like so

```
{["column1_value","column2_value","column3_value"]=>count,... etc ...}
```

Whats the best/easiest way to convert this into a multiple level hash?. Eg

```
{column1_value:{
  column2_value:{
   column3_value1: count,
   column3_value2: count
  }
  column2_value2:{ ...}
 }
 column2_value2: {....}
}
```

I get why the result is keyed by an array, but it's not particularly easy to use!.

Comment: `group_by` is external to AREL. You can always do your own grouping if it's not producing the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, if you prefer an iterative approach:

```
a = {[:a, :b, :c]=> 1, [:a, :b, :d]=>2, [:a, :c, :e]=>3}

a.each_with_object({}) { |((*keys, l), v), m|
  keys.inject(m) {|mm, key|
    mm[key] ||= {}
  }[l] = v
}
# {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>2}, :c=>{:e=>3}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def hashify(array, value, hash)
  key = array.shift
  if array.empty?
    hash[key] = value
  else
    hashify(array, value, hash[key] ||= {})
  end
end

a = {[:a, :b, :c]=> 1, [:a, :b, :d]=>2, [:a, :c, :e]=>3}
h = {}
a.each { |k, v| hashify(k, v, h) }

h
# => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1, :d=>2}, :c=>{:e=>3}}}
```

Comment: Also a good answer. I wish I could accept both. I'm going to accept the iterative one as much as I like recursion defining a method for this one case seems overkill.